# Run Javascript if Select values =

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I make a script to calculate number.

But i want this script to be work only when user select dropdown to **text2** *(value=5)*

But this script is not working *(nothing happened when run the script)* :(
Can anyone help or suggest me getting started with this script Please.

```
<select id="stt" onchange="copy()">
     <option value="">Select</option>
     <option value="8">text1</option>
     <option value="5">text2</option>
     <option value="4">text3</option>     
</select><br>

Calculate<br>
<input type="text" id="input">
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="result">

<script>
    function copy() {
       if (document.getElementById("stt").value == "5") {
           $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#input").keyup(function(){
                 var val1 = +$("#input").val();
                 $("#result").val(val1*79);
              });
           });
       }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery, you didn't tag the question as such, there's no reference to jQuery in the code, yet you seem to be using jQuery code?

Comment: "But this script is not working" — Define "not working". What behaviour do you expect? What behaviour do you actually get? What have you done to try to debug this code?

Comment: ur code a bit mess, your document.ready show that you using jquery, but ur `if`, `function`use javascript, did you copy the jquery from somewhere and paste it without knowing what it actually do?

Comment: That is a strange mix of jquery and vanilla javascript.  You would help youself *hugely* if you learnt to indent your code correctly.  Also what are you trying to do with `+$("#input")`?  The `+` looks like a syntax error to me

Comment: What a mess... Delete and start fresh

Comment: Agreed! document.ready shouldn't be there and always compare using the === operator

Comment: I copied from my friend project and i thought it's a javascript, sorry about that :(

Comment: @BogdanM there is a reason why both `==` and `===` exist. Saying to always use `===` is incorrect. You only need to use a triple equals when you want to ensure values being compared are of the same type. So 2 === '2' would be `false`, and `true` with `==`.

Comment: @wf4 I meant specifically in Javascript, have a look here http://www.impressivewebs.com/why-use-triple-equals-javascipt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

****EDIT****: Changed `$("#input").on("change"` with `$("#input").on("keypress"`.

New working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L69dp/1/

HTML Code:

```
<select id="stt">
    <option value="">
        Select
    </option>

    <option value="8">
        text1
    </option>

    <option value="5">
        text2
    </option>

    <option value="4">
        text3
    </option>
</select><br>
Calculate<br>

<form>
    <input id="input" type="text"> <input disabled="true" id="result" type=
    "text">
</form>
```

JS Code:

```
$(function() {
function calculate() {
    var sttval = $("#stt").val();
    if (sttval == "5") {
        var val1 = $("#input").val();
        $("#result").val(val1 * 79);
    } else {
        $("#result").val("");
    }
}
$("#stt").on("change", function() {
    calculate();
});
$("#input").on("keypress", function() {
    calculate();
});}());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script>
var value;
function copy() {
    value=document.getElementById("stt").value; //get the value of select everytime it change the value
}

function dd()
{
    if(value=="5")//if the value is 5 do the code below
    {
      var val1= document.getElementById('input');
     document.getElementById('result').value=val1.value*79;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body >

<select id="stt" onchange="copy()">
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <option value="8">text1</option>
 <option value="5">text2</option>
 <option value="4">text3</option>     
</select><br>

<input type="text" id="input"  oninput="dd()" >
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="result">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou It works , But this function always calculate all time
I would like this calculate feature will be work only when user select dropdown to text2 (value=5)

Comment: i'm sorry i forgot what you need, i updated my answer, sorry it takes long for me to reply..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the jquery library:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Put this before your existing script block.

Also, you do not need $(document).ready(function(){} inside the copy() function.